Ingresar datos de DataGridView a base de datos usando arquiterctura por capas (DAL, BLL, UI) en VS 2022
Alguien sabe como ingresar varios datos que se encuentren en un DataGridView a una base de datos usando arquitectura por capas con interfaces y clases?
Quiero ingresar los datos que obtengo del DataGridView a una base de datos pero no he podido hacerlo y necesito ayuda. De momento el codigo que tengo solo me guarda la primera linea de mi DataGridView pero al momento de que el foreach intenta almacenar las demas filas me sale el error 'No se ha inicializado la propiedad ConnectionString'
foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (fila.IsNewRow) continue;
    int idProducto = fila.Cells[8].Value != null ? Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[8].Value) : 0;
    int cantidad = fila.Cells[5].Value != null ? Convert.ToInt32(fila.Cells[5].Value) : 0;
    decimal precio = fila.Cells[2].Value != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells[2].Value) : 0;
    float descuento = fila.Cells[3].Value != null ? Convert.ToSingle(fila.Cells[3].Value) : 0f;
    decimal precioTotal = fila.Cells[7].Value != null ? Convert.ToDecimal(fila.Cells[7].Value) : 0m;

    try
    {
        resultadoDetalle = logicaDetalle.NuevoDetalleFactura(cantidad, precio, descuento, idFactura, idProducto, idSerie, precioTotal);
        MessageBox.Show("Resultado: " + resultadoDetalle); 
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error al insertar: " + error.Message);
    }
}

Agradeceria mucho si alguien ya le sucedio este problema y me pueda ayudar o explicarme de manera distinta como ingresar los datos a la BD ya que me encuentro estancado en este punto. gracias!

Saludos. Verifica que tu clase/capa desde donde inicializas logicaDetalle tenga su constructor que inicialice el conector (con el string de conexión)... también que dentro de NuevoDetalleFactura (el conector) no lo estes liberando (hacer null o aplicar Dispose); sino hasta el final del foreach agrega método que lo haga e invócalo.

Debes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código de logicaDetalle.NuevoDetalleFactura, junto con todo el código de las funciones que puedas tener dentro de ella, hasta llegar a donde tienes la conexión con la base de dato
